# Run process as if on a single-core machine to find a bug

Tags: linux, process, process-management, multithreading, thread

I have a bug in my Linux app that is reproducable only on single-core CPUs.
To debug it, I want to start the process from the command line so that it is limited to 1 CPU even on my multi-processor machine.

Is it possible to change this for a particular process, e.g. to run it so that it does not run (its) multiple threads on multiple processors?

Comment: It's up to the program running in the process how many threads it creates.

Comment: How does your application determine how many threads to spawn? Depending on how your app checks the number of cores (e.g. via `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`, `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)`, `/proc/cpuinfo`, `cpuid`, etc) there may be different approaches to fake the core count. That said, as suggested by @JohanMyréen, at that point it may be easier to hardcode how many threads to spawn.

Comment: By the way, it may be worth mentioning what language and threading library you are using.

Comment: Would not be easier changing you own sources? (....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **taskset** from `util-linux`.

> The masks
>          may be specified in hexadecimal (with or without a leading "0x"), or as
>          a CPU list with the --cpu-list option.  For example,
>
> ```
>        0x00000001  is processor #0,
>
>        0x00000003  is processors #0 and #1,
>
>        0xFFFFFFFF  is processors #0 through #31,
>
>        32          is processors #1, #4, and #5,
>
>        --cpu-list 0-2,6
>                    is processors #0, #1, #2, and #6.
>
>    When  taskset returns, it is guaranteed that the given program has been
>    scheduled to a legal CPU.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer by @Ipor to limit program to one CPU hardware core/thread one may use `taskset 1 prog [args]`

Also, there is a way to explicitly prohibit a process from cloning (not sure about apps that use `fork` though, checked only for `clone` sys call).

The program to limit number of processes a program can have (threads) is `prlimit --nproc=1 prog [args]`. I've tried to use it with `rsync` and got "fork unavailable... error in IPC" and the end - `rsync` is written not to work as one thread.

```
strace prlimit --nproc=1 rsync
```

Running `strace` has shown as described in SO link below return value from `clone` call is `-1 EAGAIN (resource temporary unavailable).`

P.S. idea taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637451/is-there-a-way-force-a-program-to-use-only-1-thread.